# What is the best way to split large MongoDB collections?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

#### Situation

We use **MongoDB (v. 4.0.13)** to store sensor data from IoT devices. We have two collections that store the same type of documents. Each document has a DateTime attribute. We use **PyMongo (v. 3.7.2)** and **Python (3.7.2)** to retrieve the data from the MongoDB database. More complex aggregation queries are quite common. The situation is as follows:

- The first collection is for storing documents that aren't older than one month. Documents older than one month are deleted regularly every day. This is to ensure a reasonably sized collection, which is used to retrieve data into our web application.
- The second collection holds all documents ever received and we never delete any documents from this collection. This is to ensure we have detailed historical data for every device. This collection is used when we need detailed historical data, that is older than one month.

#### Problem

We expect these collections to receive a lot of data - in tens of millions. Consequently, the second collection is bound to reach a size that is unmanageable and all queries will take a significant amount of time, which will be, at some point, unacceptable.

We use indexes (which sped up our queries significantly) and are looking for another way to speed up our queries and manage our collections in a way that lets us keep the time and CPU utilization of these queries reasonably low and stable.

#### Questions

1. Is there a way to split this large collection into multiple smaller ones (of a similar size for example), but query more than one, if necessary, as if it was one collection? Let's say I wanted data that is split between two smaller collections - I would need to combine these two and then use find/aggregate on the combined data. Is there a way to achieve this?
2. Is the approach presented in question #1 feasible and MongoDB friendly? If not, are there any other ways to approach this problem?

Comment: In case you haven't yet found this, here is some useful information: [Time Series Data and MongoDB: Part 1 – An Introduction](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/time-series-data-and-mongodb-part-1-introduction).

Comment: If you queries are indexed and you are returning a small subset of your overall data indexing 10s of millions of documents should present no problems.  I can query individual documents (that are indexed) is less than 1ms in collections 50m+ documents.

Comment: Have you looked into materialized views?

Comment: Maybe not related to the question, but such functionality is provided by elasticsearch out of the box to have date based indexes. 1 index for each day. Helps is easy archival. Also supports querying using wildcard.
You may replicate try to replicate the same in mongo. but it's not straightforward, As suggested by @D.SM you can make summarised collection.  But that depends on your query patterns. Like hourly summary, minute summary, daily summary, basically a summarized view of your data

Comment: @prasad_ - Thank you, seems like a useful blogpost, I will have a look at it.

Comment: @JoeDrumgoole - Do you think that 100s of millions won't present a problem either?

Comment: @D.SM - Not yet but as far as I know, it's available from MongoDB v. 4.2 and higher ([source](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/coming-in-mongodb-42--ondemand-materialized-views))

Comment: @Holy_diver - we do have a collection for daily summaries, which we use to display historical data by month and year, but we need raw, detailed data too

Comment: Not as long as the index and working set fits in memory.

Comment: You can keep a collection for current system i.e for hot data. For archived data. You can split it into monthly collections. Something like RollingFileSytem. For much older you may store a compressed dump